# Čech functions and the axiom of choice

Tags: gn.general-topology, set-theory, axiom-of-choice

A **Čech closure function** on $\omega$ is a function $\varphi:\mathcal P(\omega)\to\mathcal P(\omega)$ such that (i) $X\subseteq\varphi(X)$ for all $X\subseteq\omega$, (ii) $\varphi(\emptyset)=\emptyset$, and (iii) $\varphi(X\cup Y)=\varphi(X)\cup\varphi(Y)$ for all $X,Y\subseteq\omega$; in other words, it obeys the Kuratowski closure axioms except possibly the idempotent law $\varphi(\varphi(X))=\varphi(X)$.

In 1947 E. Čech asked if there exists such a closure function (on any set, not necessarily $\omega$) which is also **surjective** and **nontrivial** (not the identity map). Čech's question has been answered in the affirmative [under various set-theoretic assumptions](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0166864182900608), including ZFC. [The ZFC example](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/8870/c3c8a574f24aa1ee411f82283a1076c53303.pdf) is rather complicated and makes heavy use of the axiom of choice; it seems unlikely that one could construct such a thing without choice.

**Question.** Is it consistent with ZF that there is no nontrivial surjective Čech closure function $\varphi:\mathcal P(\omega)\to\mathcal P(\omega)$?

That is, there is no function $\varphi:\mathcal P(\omega)\to\mathcal P(\omega)$ satisfying the conditions (i)-(iii) above and also (iv) for every $Y\subseteq\omega$ there exists $X\subseteq\omega$ such that $\varphi(X)=Y$, and (v) $\varphi(X)\ne X$ for some $X\subseteq\omega$. (Condition (ii) is now redundant, as it follows from (i) and (iv) that $\varphi(X)=X$ if $X$ is finite.)

Comment: I could imagine several candidate models: Maybe Cohen's model is a suitable example with the Dedekind-finite set of reals "spoiling things", but more likely would be Solovay's model where there are no MAD families, etc.

Comment: Also a candidate: the Feferman–Levy model where the reals are a countable union of countable sets, or the Truss model (although if this holds there, I'd imagine the Solovay model would already capture this).

Comment: I think it would be a good point in time to migrate this to MathOverflow. I don't have an obvious solution at hand, and I have quite a lot of things on my hands right now (which is why I might be missing something obvious).

Comment: Is it correct to think as "in ZF there's such a function" as "one can construct such a function"? More precisely, is it true (from some general principle) that if "there is such a function" is a theorem of ZF, then there exists $f_0\in P(\omega)^{P(\omega)}$ satisfying the given condition, and a formula of set theory $F(x)$ with only parameter $x$, such that for every $f\in P(\omega)^{P(\omega)}$, $F(f)$ holds iff $f=f_0$?

Comment: @bof I'd be happy with a weaker definition of "constructible". I'm just wondering whether the slogan "(exists in ZF)=(can be constructed)" has any foundation.

Comment: @YCor: Are you asking for a definable class (the class of functions such that blah blah, defined by formula) whose elements are individually not definable (so that you cannot write down such $F$'s to pick out individual elements)?

Comment: @YCor: I got a partial answer to this in [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/297738/in-what-ways-is-zf-without-choice-somewhat-constructive).

Comment: @bof Out of Theorem 1 and Theorem 2 in the Galvin-Simon paper, which one is using AC in its proof?

Comment: @Haim Looks to me like they both use choice. My guess is, if you can construct such a function without choice, it will be by a completely different method.